# Centos 5.5 remote commandline

Tags: php, exec, centos

is there a php script that i can use as commandline on another location. like "yum install" etc?

Comment: Do you want to execute PHP script via command line?

Comment: IF you are wanting to execute shell commands on your Centos box from within your PHP, look at the shell_exec() function, the exec() function, or place your shell command in backticks. Example: print(`ls /usr/pics/*.jpg`);

Comment: Sorry, cannot use backticks in above as they format code on stackoverflow

Answer (score 0):

This feature is called not php script but [Secure Shell](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Secure_Shell)

Comment: And I suggest PUTTY - http://www.chiark.greenend.org.uk/~sgtatham/putty/download.html